# Superconductivity - Radiation of charge

Tags: superconductivity

Why don’t electrons (bound to cooper pairs) - in addition to scattering - loose energy due to radiation of moving charge (which is one reason why the atom in Rutherford‘s Atomic Model cannot be stable)? Is this because they are bound to bosons and are in their energetic ground state, which does not allow us to further reduce their energy? If that is true, why is the density of states large just below the BCS energy gap but not maximum for $W \rightarrow 0$. I would think this is because only electrons with $k_F < k < h \omega_D$ form cooper pairs. But these electrons have energies well above 0.